# How can I catch an exception thrown in the onStatus method of a blocking webclient GET request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am using a WebClient right now instead of rest template to call an API.  The goal is that in a near-future sprint we would make all of our clients reactive and non-blocking, but in the short term we can use a blocking call but at least have the WebClient in place.  One thing we want to do is throw a custom exception when a 204 No Content status is returned, so that the code using the client must catch the exception

I have tried throwing exceptions from the `.onStatus(...)`, but what happens is that it doesn't throw the `PersonNotFoundException` from the code below, it throws a `reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException` with the `PersonNotFoundException` nested

Client code

```java
public PersonDto getPersonDetails(String lastName) throws PersonNotFoundException{
    return webClient.get()
              .uri(personEndpoint + "/{lastName}", lastName)
              .retrieve()
              .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT),
                            clientResponse -> Mono.error(new PersonNotFoundException("Person " + lastName + "Not Found")))
              .bodyToMono(PersonDto.class)
              .block();
}
```

Calling Code

```java
 PersonDto personDto = null;
 try {
    personDto = personServiceCLient.getPersonDetails("Smith");
 } catch (PersonNotFoundException e) {
    //do custom logic for 204 errors
 }
```

The result I would hope for is that the `PersonNotFoundException` would be caught in the catch statement of the calling code.  The result is that a ReactiveException is thrown, and the uncaught exception terminates my program:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: com.sample.demo.PersonNotFoundException: Person Smith Not Found
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:91) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494) ~[reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.demo.client.PersonServiceClient.getPersonDetails(PersonServiceClient.java.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sample.demo.PersonServiceImpl.addPersonToHousehold(PersonServiceImpl.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: It seems `onStatus` doesn't work with `block` method. I hope some people can explain this reason...

Answer (score 5):

your custom exception `PersonNotFoundException` gets wrapped into  `reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException`. To avoid such situations always use `RuntimeException`. Now you have to extend your custom exception class from `RuntimeException`.

For Example:

```java
public class PersonNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using the Exceptions util class. Might be too late now but oh well.

```
public PersonDto getPersonDetails(String lastName) throws PersonNotFoundException{
return webClient.get()
          .uri(personEndpoint + "/{lastName}", lastName)
          .retrieve()
          .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT),
                        clientResponse -> throw Exceptions.propagate(new PersonNotFoundException("Person " + lastName + "Not Found")))
          .bodyToMono(PersonDto.class)
          .block();
```

}

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a valid solution.Produces:Syntax error on token "throw"